# Failed to decode downloaded font in react

Tags: reactjs, fonts, font-face

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Gumela;
  src: url('../src/fonts/*');
}

*{
  font-family: "Gumela";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

I used this in visual studio while working on a react app navbar but the browser keeps showing font couldn't be downloaded error, I tried changing the path as well as redownloading the font but nothing changed, please help me with this

Comment: Whats this URL? Why is there a `*`? Should be the filename of the font.

Comment: i saw it on a youtube tutorial but adding the font name or so doesnt change anything as well , the issue is different

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `@font-face` rule is complete.
It should rather look something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Gumela;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(../src/fonts/gumela.woff) format('woff2');
}
```

Better specify a `format` and the `font-weight`.

#### Check the path/URL

you can easily test this by entering the font files url in you address bar:

`yourPage.com/src/fonts/gumela.woff`

Common mistake:
You fonts folder is actually in your css directory. So you src should rather be:

`src: url(fonts/gumela.woff) format('woff2')`

So doublecheck your paths. As a last resort you might also try absolute paths.